# How to know default gateway without dhcp

Tags: networking, router, lan, dhcp, gateway

Sometimes i use some wifi, maybe in public places or hotels.
Sometimes they do not have DHCP Server on they router, and they do not provide LAN IP Settings, and maybe they also DO NOT KNOW what LAN Settings are.
The internet connection works, but you can't connect because you don't have an ip.
Ok you can set it manually, and if you guess the default gateway, usually works.
But if you don't know, or can't guess the default gateway, how you can know it?
Is there some p

Answer (score 1):

You need at least an IP and a Subnet Mask. With this two you could calculate the network range, network ip (the first one), broadcast ip (the last one), usualy the default gateway is the first IP + one.

Answer (score 0):

Someone would have to tell you the settings, including which IP address to use. For a public Wi-Fi network, this isn't very practical, so it's unlikely that anyone would intentionally set up a public network without a DHCP server. Most likely the network is malfunctioning or misconfigured.